# Custom maps for Steam Version?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Does anyone know if it's possible to play downloaded custom maps in the steam version of the game? And how? I was never able to get it to work with Heroes 5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to play downloaded custom maps in the Steam version of Might & Magic: Heroes 6.

Once you obtain the `.scm` file for the map you want to play, put it into the folder `My Documents\Might & Magic Heroes VI\Scenario\`. You may have to create the `Scenario` folder, but the `Might & Magic Heroes VI` should exist in your `My Documents` folder if you have already run the game. Once you do this, the map should appear at the bottom of the scenario list when creating a custom or multiplayer game.